# Nesting CSS Classes in Html

Tags: css

I need something for a dynamic project, and what I want is to make a class that every header element takes some properties, **the children can be or not be direct descendants**, however, inside that class can be another class that must overwrite the first class properties... I want those classes to be nested like 3-4 times.... is there a way to do this, to not take too much css space?

```css
.something1 h1{
  color: green;
}

.something2 h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <div>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <div><div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      </div></div>
      <div class='something2'>
        <div>
        <h1>Red</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eauwr8zo/1/

Answer (score 1):

**Using**  with  **`>`** **in css**

```css
.something1 > h1{
  color: green ;
}

.something2 > h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      <div class='something2'>
        <h1>Red</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using**  with **`!important;`** **in css**

```css
.something1 > h1{
  color: green !important;
}

.something2 h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      <div class='something2'>
        <h1>Red</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct descendant combinator `>`.

```css
.something1 h1 {
  color: green;
}

.something2 > div > h1, .something2 > h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <div>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <div><div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      </div></div>
      <div class='something2'>
        <div>
        <h1>Red</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or if can't find a combination to use `>` that suits your random html,
then you can add a new selector by being even more specific by adding the same class multiple times.

```css
.something1 h1,
.something1 .something1 h1{
  color: green;
}

.something2 h1,
.something2 .something2 h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <div>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <div><div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      </div></div>
      <div class='something2'>
        <div>
        <h1>Red</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, the children is not necessary to be direct descendants

Comment: @Brada You can find a combination to use `>` that works for you, or add the same class multiple times. https://jsfiddle.net/eauwr8zo/2/

Comment: Yes, i know, but I need to update the classes with PHP and in the end the resulting file may be some big....

Answer (score 0):

Add the ">" simbol to `.something1 > h1` and `.something2 > h1`, like this it will only affect its direct child:

```css
.something1 > h1{
  color: green;
}

.something2 > h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='something1'>
  <h1>Green</h1>
  <div class='something2'>
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <div class='something1'>
      <h1>Green</h1>
      <div class='something2'>
        <h1>Red</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```